# In circular motion, what's preventing me from calculating the circumference of the circle, dividing it by time to find the speed of the object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, orbital-motion

There are equations to solve for the speed in circular motion. However, is there anything preventing me from calculating the circumference from the given radius, and then divide that over the time to complete the orbit, since the circumference is the distance the orbiting object travels.

Comment: The question to ask your self is: do you have that data?

Comment: I do...and then?

Comment: If you have the data, then you can do that very thing. But often you have other kinds of data.

Comment: May I ask a question in return? Why did you think you might not be able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you have $2{\pi}r$ and you know the time in which you traveled it, then you could find speed. Nothing prevents this.

Comment: @Jimnosperm Multitasking will be the end of me...

Comment: Welp, this is it. So simple.